# Convert a transformation matrix from world-space to camera-space using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, coordinate-transformation

I have a transformation matrix, in world space. I need to convert it to local(camera) space.

I have done the reverse of this (Local - to - world) using:

```
    Eigen::Matrix3f R0; //rotation matrix
    Eigen::Vector3f T0; // xyz translation values
    Eigen::Vector3f C0; //result

    R0.transposeInPlace();  //invert rotation matrix

    C0 = -R0 * T0;   //return world-space coordinate
```

Can I simply run this exact same thing to invert it the other way? Or is it a different equation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely look into studying linear algebra if you wish to continue to work with matrices.

In your case, you should be able to solve for T0 if you left-multiply by the matrix inverse on both sides:

`C0 = -R0 * T0`

`-R1 * C0 = -R1 * -R0 * T0` (`R1` is the inverse of `R0`)

`-R1 * C0 = T0`

So to get T0 from C0, you'd negate and left-multiply C0 by the inverse of R0, which would be the matrix you started with before you called `R0.transposeInPlace();`

Comment: Thanks! So in code, can I just : R1 = R0.transposeInPlace(); T0 = -R1 * C0;  Is that right?

Comment: .transposeInPlace() doesn't return the matrix, it will transpose R0. Use .transpose() instead. Also consider storing R0 and R1 outside of the function so you won't have to perform a matrix transpose every time you do a coordinate transform.